# How to compare value of month and day from a date in oracle 11g and use it in where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have a table 'table1' where months of a year are numbered from 1 to 12 in rows and 1 to 31 days of month are in form of column.

There is another table 'table2' where dates and some other values are stored. The date has DATE datatype. I need to fetch date from that 'table2' and compare values of month and day and insert values into 'table1'  accordingly. 
**Example** if date from 'table2' is 21-JUN-2017, then value should be inserted in 21st colunm(day) and 6th row(month) in 'table1'. How can I implement the same in Oracle 11g using SQL?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: A table does not have a fixed number of rows ... you can have one column for month-of-year and 31 columns for each day of the month but saying you have "months of a year are numbered from 1 to 12 in rows" does not make much sense. Please post a [MCVE] including the DDL statements for your table and any DML statements for the data they contain.

Comment: it looks like `to_char()` with an appropriate format mask is what you're looking for. Hint, the format for numbered months is `mm` and the format for days is `dd`.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: DDL for table1:- 
CREATE TABLE table1 (Month Number,1 Number,2 Number,...31 Number,);

DML for table1:- 
Insert into table1(Month) VALUES (1);....Insert into table1(Month) VALUES (12);


What I need to do:- 
Suppose I need insert value=x in table1 and the date retrived from table2 is 21-JUN-2017

UPDATE table1
SET 21 = x
WHERE Month=06;

Comment: What will you do if there are two different rows in `table2` where the date is the same, like 21-JUN-2017? How do you plan to **insert** two different values into the same column in the same row?

Comment: @mathguy it is assumed that there will be no multiple values in same column and same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

Simplify your table - do not store 32 columns (month and 31 days) instead just store month, day and value and `PIVOT` the output as required:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  month NUMBER(2,0),
  day   NUMBER(2,0),
  value VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_column ),
         EXTRACT( DAY   FROM date_column ),
         value
  FROM   table2;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT month, d1, d2, d3, d4, /* ..., */ d31
FROM   table1
PIVOT  ( MAX( value ) FOR day IN (
           1 AS d1, 2 AS d2, 3 As d3, 4 AS d4, /* ..., */ 31 AS d31
       ) );
```

**Update**:

> DDL for table1:-
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (Month Number,1 Number,2 Number,...31 Number,);
> ```

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT month, d1, d2, /* ..., */ d31
  FROM   ( SELECT EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_column ) AS month,
                  EXTRACT( DAY   FROM date_column ) AS day,
                  value
           FROM   table2 )
  PIVOT  ( MAX( value ) FOR day IN (
             1 AS d1, 2 AS d2, /* ..., */ 31 AS d31
         ) );
```

Or use `MERGE INTO` if you want to update the existing rows.

Comment: Thanks @MT0. Your solution works like a charm. Also it helped me to save data by creating only month,day and values column in table1.